# BotFramework - Send Message without text

Tags: node.js, botframework

I want to send a message object without any text. Here is what I am doing

```
const navButtonsMsg = new BotBuilder.Message(session)
  .text("Hello")
  .suggestedActions(
    BotBuilder.SuggestedActions.create(
      session,
      [
        BotBuilder.CardAction.imBack(session, "red", "red"),
        BotBuilder.CardAction.imBack(session, "blue", "blue"),
        BotBuilder.CardAction.imBack(session, "green", "green")
      ]
    )
  );
  session.send(navButtonsMsg);
```

Here is the output!

[image]

I don't want **Hello** text. If I remove the **text()** method, this happens:

```
const navButtonsMsg = new BotBuilder.Message(session)
  .suggestedActions(
    BotBuilder.SuggestedActions.create(
      session,
      [
        BotBuilder.CardAction.imBack(session, "red", "red"),
        BotBuilder.CardAction.imBack(session, "blue", "blue"),
        BotBuilder.CardAction.imBack(session, "green", "green")
      ]
    )
  );
  session.send(navButtonsMsg);
```

[image]

I cannot use **Prompts.choice** as they will require that user type or click something from the prompts. These buttons appear as part of the suggested actions which are optional for the user, and disappears on click or user types something (although disappearance is not mandatory, but its nice). How can I achieve that?

I want to have these suggested actions with the Welcome card as shown in images. No text above or below the card.

Comment: "I cannot use Prompts.choice as they will require that user enters something from the prompts." < Why? the user can click on the choices

Comment: @NicolasR, actually even if user clicks, that is equivalent to user typing. Anyway, I don't want to make it mandatory for user to click or type something from the choices. These are suggested actions, not mandatory actions. I will edit my question though.

Comment: Ok, wasn't sure about your formulation, but with your comment I understand why you prefer Suggested Actions for that (I also had the same "issue" with Prompts, being able to do something else). Anyway, I think you will be locked on this point, I don't think you can avoid this blank text. But it may be better to inform your user that (s)he can type anything or use the buttons, no?

Comment: Hi! I these suggested actions are actually accompanied by cards. So user knows he can click on card actions, but just that I don't want that text. Also what do you meant by __use the buttons__!

Comment: In my scenario, I had Suggested Actions (= buttons) but the user also had the possibility to write a query to do something else, so I tell the user that he can type his/her query OR click on the buttons (= the suggested actions). For your case, what do you have in your cards?

Comment: Yes, I think that will do, can you post a snippet or some doc link for that. Buttons instead of suggested actions will do. Buttons will not disappear though, but that's not priority. In cards I have an image, and a bunch of buttons. Bot framework refers to them as card actions.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, when I say buttons it's the buttons generated by the Suggested Actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug in the webchat control](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/870).  I'll be talking to the team and see if we can get to a resolution.  I will update this answer as I get more information.  For now know that you are not doing anything wrong and you are taking the right approach.

Update 3/16/2018:
I have spoken with the Webchat dev team.  This is now on their radar and they will be working on a fix.

Update 3/26/2018:
The fix should be implemented in the latest webchat code now.